# Merge opentok archives

Tags: video, video-streaming, webrtc, video-processing, opentok

I have a use-case where I create multiple archives for a opentok session.

This [link](https://tokbox.com/blog/single-file-archive-yes-you-can/) states that we can merge multiple archives, Is there any other post talking about the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

OpenTok QA staff here,

The link you provide states that that functionality is no longer supported. Anyway, you can use FFMPEG to merge or concatenate the different archives you create.
Either you use manual archiving (you use the REST API) or the auto-archiving feature, you have to download all the archives for that session, and process them offline.